# How to get a Cloud Functions Callback URL to use during an API callback after it completes a money transaction, Flutter App

Tags: flutter, function, dart, cloud, callbackurl

I need a callback URL so that when a mobile money API completes a payment transaction, my app can receive a message about the transaction status. I'm building a flutter app. I have seen that cloud functions may be the answer. So, I need help on how to get started on creating this callback URL.

I'm yet to try anything because all the material I have seen talks about JavaScript and websites. I need material on doing this in the flutter mobile app.

Comment: do you want to call the URL function as soon as your money API function competes?

Comment: Yes, I want the money API to send their response via the callback url, then the app receives the message and handles it

Answer (score 0):

look at this snippet I hope it helps

```dart
// await for your first function t
   await moneyFuntion()
        .whenComplete(() async  => await anotherAPIFuntion())
         .onError((error, stackTrace) {
      log("$error");
```